# Вывод из BD некого количества значений по убыванию

Tags: php, mysql

Вид таблицы id-exp.
Есть список id 1,342,3,64,85,7427. Нужно вывести этот список по убыванию, в зависимости от количества exp. Есть у кого-нибудь какие-то идеи? Может, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё предельно просто

```
select * from `table` where `id` in(1, 342, 3, 64, 85, 7427) order by `id`, `exp` desc
```

Comment: Это, конечно, крутой вариант. Но Есть определённый список id.

Comment: @Vlmake поправил ответ.